# How do i detect if view in on top position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used this code to get the element to fade in when scrolling:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $(window).scroll( function() {
              $('#floatingDIV4').each( function() {
                 var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                 var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

                 if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                     $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'}, 500);
                 }
              });
           });
        });
    </script>
```

i try to find a code that makes the element that is appearing at scroll to fade out at the top position but i don't find any. Do you have any ideas about it?

Edit:

The answers was really good but the codes didn't work.

Comment: for performance , try `debounce` & `caching elements` .

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                 $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0, opacity: 0  },'slow');
             }
```

if this answer is correct then please mark it as answer for others....

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
             $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0,
                               opacity: 0 
                             },'slow');
         }
```

This will scroll to the top, and fade at the same time.
However if you was looking for the code to fade only when it has finished moving to the top, you could use:

```
    if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
             $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0,}, 
                     complete: function(){
                         $(this).animate({opacity:0})
                     )};
      }
```

But so that the box is visible as it is fading, the `scrollTop:` value would need to be higher than 0, eg. the height of the box in px.

Answer (score 0):

may be this help you

```
function show_coords(event)
{
    var x=event.clientX;
    var y=event.clientY;
    alert("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
}
```

compare the value of X ,Y with some predefined value